# C program to fill an array

Tags: c

**The problem is to fill the array like this if n = 4**

**output of my code:**

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

**desired output:**

```
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 3
3 4 3 2
4 3 2 1
```

My friend said this problem is easy but I can't figure it out, please help. The code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    int a[100][100];
    printf("Enter the value of n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=j;      
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        { 
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }        
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The array `int a[10]` has valid indices 0 thru 9.  Fix all your loops.  Instead of `for(i = 1; i <=n; i++ )`, you need to use `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: When posting, please include the actual output of your program and your desired output.

Comment: Please show text as formatted text, not as link to an image containing plain text.

Comment: `a[i][j]=j;` This assigns a value that only depends on the row. This is not what you want. As a first improvement try `= i+j` instead. Then see how you must adjust the remaining deviations

Comment: Is your task to fill an array with that pattern or just to print that pattern. These are different requirements with different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always start counting from `1` upwards, but you don't have a loop where you count backwards, like in the desired output.

I would recommend to use two for loops, one which counts upwards and one downwards. Also you don't need an array, you can print out the numbers directly:

```
main()
{
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter the value of n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", j);     
        }
        for(j = n; j > n-i; j--)
        {
            printf("%d ", j); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```